# Java leer objetos de un fichero

Tags: java

Intentando leer y escribir objetos de un fichero con extensión .dat me he encontrado con el problema de que me da un error de casteo al intentar iniciar de nuevo el programa y recuperar los datos guardados en el fichero donde se ha realizado la persistencia.

En la aplicación se intenta hacer persitencia de datos introducidos por consola, relacionados con libros.

```
    final String FILESTORE_PATH = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + ("MartinNauzet_libros.dat");
List<Libro> memStore = new ArrayList<Libro>();

@Override
public void open() {

    boolean cont = true;

    try {

        FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(
                new File("C:\\Users\\nauze\\Desktop\\Prueba\\MartinNauzet_libros.dat"));
        ObjectInputStream oi = new ObjectInputStream(fi);
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\nauze\\Desktop\\Prueba\\MartinNauzet_libros.dat");

        if(file.exists()) {

            while (cont) {

                Object object = oi.readObject();

                if (object != null)
                    memStore.add((Libro) object);
                else
                    cont = false;
            }
        }
        else {

            file.createNewFile();

        }

        fi.close();
        oi.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FICHERO NO ENCONTRADO");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR INICIALIZANDO EL STREAM");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public void close() {

    try {
        FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(
                new File("C:\\Users\\nauze\\Desktop\\Prueba\\MartinNauzet_libros.dat"));
        ObjectOutputStream o = new ObjectOutputStream(f);

        // Write objects to file

        o.writeObject(memStore);

        o.close();
        f.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("FICHERO NO ENCONTRADO");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ERROR INICIALIZANDO EL STREAM");
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería muchísimo cualquier tipo de aportación. Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Implementa la clase Libro la interfaz "Serializeable"?

Comment: Sí, actualizaré el post ya que ahora mismo me está dando una excepción por casteo.

Comment: Escribe memstore (una lista de libros) hasta el fichero.  Pero cuando lee objectos del fichero, los trata como Libro cuando en realidad son un listo de Libros.  (Tengo sentido?)  Es decir cuado lee, debe ser List<Libro>.add(Libro) y lo que hace es List<Libro>.add(List<Libro>).

Comment: @naumb además del objeto Libro, sería buena idea que agregaras un ejemplo de tu archivo .dat

Comment: Es decir, cómo deberia de hacer realmente el casteo, además adjunatré ahora una captura de .dat

Comment: La imagen del archivo que he adjuntado es sin aún tener ningún objeto, si es necesario alguna información extra intentaré adjuntarlo lo antes posible.

Comment: En lugar de Object object = oi.readObject(); ponga List<Libro>object = oi.readObject();

Comment: @Duston eso me acaba dando el mismo error, acabo de comprobarlo. Muchas gracias aún así

Comment: Adentro el dat, tenes un libro o un arraylist<Libro>, pareciera que tenes un arreglo y queres sacar un libro. Por eso te da error de casteo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> La idea es agarrar a un objeto que sea serializable, serializarlo a un archivo llamado, datos.dat (queda en la carpeta del proyecto junto a la carpeta src), y luego deserializar si es que existe la palabra, a un Objeto y luego usarlo. En el ejemplo uso un ArrayList, ArrayList es Serializable por default, hay que implementar en la clase Libro la libreria Serializable; uso el main para poner el ejemplo.

```
public static void main( String [] args ) {
     //inicializo la lista de libros
     ArrayList<Libro> lista = new ArrayList<Libro>();
     //Agrego 2 libros a la lista;
     lista.add(new Libro("1984","Orwell"));
     lista.add(new Libro("100 años de soledad","Marquez"));  
     //serializo la lista (la guardo en datos.dat) 
     serializar(lista);
     //deserializo la lista y la recorro imprimiendo el toString() implicitamente
     for (Libro libro : deserializar()) {
         System.out.println(libro);
     }   
}
//Este es el método para serializar (Guardar el objeto en datos.dat)
public static void serializar(ArrayList<Libro> lista) {

try
{
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("datos.dat");
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(lista);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();
} 
catch (IOException ioe) 
{
    ioe.printStackTrace();
}
}   

//aca deserializo el objeto que esta en datos.dat y lo guardo en la lista biblioteca 
public static ArrayList<Libro> deserializar() {
 ArrayList<Libro> biblioteca = new ArrayList<Libro>();

 try
 {
     FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("datos.dat");
     ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

     biblioteca = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();

     ois.close();
     fis.close();
 } 
 catch (IOException ioe) 
 {
     ioe.printStackTrace();

 } 
 catch (ClassNotFoundException c) 
 {
     System.out.println("Class not found");
     c.printStackTrace();

 }

 //Devuelvo la biblioteca  
 return biblioteca;
 }
```

> Ahora muestro como serializar a la clase libro.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Libro implements Serializable {
private String titulo;
private String autor;

public Libro(String titulo,String autor) {
  this.titulo=titulo;
  this.autor=autor;
}

public String getTitulo() {
    return titulo;
}
//getters y setters.

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Libro [titulo=" + titulo + ", autor=" + autor + "]";
}

}
```